# On click is not working for inflateview widgets

Tags: android, view, onclick, layout-inflater

In my activity i am inflating layout and i am giving onclick to button and layout it's not working.

MyActivity inflating code :

```
 LayoutInflater langListInflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View booksListView = new View(BookActivity.this);
    booksListView =            langListInflate.inflate(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.more_books_items),
            null);
    Button b = (Button) booksListView.findViewById(R.id.likes_button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Rating bar click");
            Intent intent = new Intent(BookActivity.this,
                    RatingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is your mean about not working? please post `more_books_items` layout

Comment: what does "not work" mean?

Comment: you only infalte but where do you add the view to the activity?

Comment: in xml i am already included this layout.I am try to sending the xml code but it's not updated

Comment: i am inflating layout in xml like this<include layout:@layout/more_books_items/>